# 13.04 on Chromebook series 3 ARM WONT BOOT!

Tags: 13.04, chromebook

I have installad 13.04 on my chromebook (SNOW Premier G). All went well, but after reboot it does not boot into ubuntu.
I get a black screen with a cursus blinking. 
Where do i go from here??
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I am using the XE303 with ChrUbuntu 12.04.

In theory 13.04 should work too but I think there is no packaged version of ChrUbuntu for 13.04 so if you don't know what you are doing, I recommend the original 12.04.

The install instructions for 12.04: http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.hu/2012/10/arm-chrubuntu-1204-alpha-1-now.html